# Building Flex SDK 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, ant

I have downloaded Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 and modified some of the source files. Now I want to build these files and make a release.

I am running the ANT utility to build the SDK.

I receive lots of errors.

```
Buildfile: C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\build.xml
    [echo] Please set the environment variable ANT_OPTS to -Xmx256m

clean:

framework:
[compc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\flex-config.xml
[compc] Loading configuration file C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\projects\framework\framework-config.xml
[compc] C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\projects\framework\src\FrameworkClasses.as(1): col: 1 Error: The definition of base class Object was not found.
[compc] 
[compc] ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[compc] ^
[compc] 
[compc] C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\graphics\BitmapSmoothingQuality.as(1): col: 1 Error: The definition of base class Object was not found.
[compc] 
[compc] ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[compc] ^
[compc] 
[compc] C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\graphics\BitmapScaleMode.as(1): col: 1 Error: The definition of base class Object was not found.
[compc] 
[compc] ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
[compc] ^
[compc] 
[compc] C:\Program Files\Adobe\CustomSDK\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\CursorManager.as(1): col: 1 Error: The definition of base class Object was not found.
[compc] 
[compc] ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thats the framework which we work on Astra Bear :)

Comment: Why don't you use [Apache Flex](http://flex.apache.org/)? Would be more natural to modify sources on a living open source project and share your changes with the community.